# Capture FM radio in Qt Symbian

Tags: qt, audio, symbian, capture

I'm trying to capture FM radio with Qt and my Symbian device (C7-00 Belle Refresh), but no effect, what is wrong? Is it possible at all?

[Audio Input Routing Symbian API](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Archived%3aAudio_Input_Routing_Symbian_API)

```
audiosource = new QAudioCaptureSource(this);
audiosource->setAudioInput("FM Radio");

QAudioEncoderSettings settings;
settings.setCodec("audio/vorbis");
settings.setQuality(QtMultimediaKit::HighQuality);

capture = new QMediaRecorder(audiosource, this);
capture->setEncodingSettings(settings, QVideoEncoderSettings(), "audio/mp4");
capture->setOutputLocation(QUrl('e:/record.mp4'));
capture->record();

QTimer::singleShot(seconds * 1000, capture, SLOT(stop()))
```

Comment: Have you used `QAudioCaptureSource::isAvailable ()` to check if "FM Radio" is available at all as an input source?